# Editing .ttf file with Python and Fonttools

Tags: python, ttx-fonttools

I want to edit a glyph in a `.ttf` font file using FontTools in Python. For example, I want to get the glyph for the letter `i` (Unicode: 0x00ED), remove its dot, then set this as the glyph for the letter `ı` (used in the Turkish alphabet, Unicode: 0x0131). But I can't find any way to edit a glyph. What is the best approach for a function like that?

Comment: I suggest you simply use [this](https://tophix.com/font-tools/font-editor) website, you can edit your font online